# IP cam/dvr protocols (xmeye example)

Tags: android, ip-camera, onvif

I have a potential project to do and i am going through research about what it takes.
Project would include viewing/controling IP cameras and DVRs. An example application i was looking at was XMEye.

I am not looking into any code or particular implementation but general directions.

Questions:

1) how does qr code autodiscovery work? is that some kond of automatic dynamic dns setting where such device has guid serial number that acts as hostname in classic dyndns? (already input into cloud db where cam reports its current ip address)

2) does xmeye app, for example, rely on devices being onvif compliant or it supports some other protocols? if so, which?

Comment: similar question https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6160/identifying-protocol-in-a-pcap-file (answered but not yet useful)